# Javascript override function with generated name

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I need to override (enrich) a Javascript function. Problem is the function is generated automatically:

```
var original_function = getFunction('someID'); // eval('someID');
```

My code will be something like this:

```
var f = function(arg) { 
 do_some_stuff(); 
 original_function(arg);  
 do_another_stuff(); 
}
```

And now when other part of code calls `getFunction('someID')` the `f('someID')` will be returned.

How to override the original function, when we know it's name or we have only a function object?

Comment: This looks like perfectly working example already. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function someFunc (arg) { alert(arg)}


function injectFunc(original, injection, inject_after) {
if(typeof original === "string") original = window[original];
return function() {
    if(!inject_after) injection.apply(this, arguments);
    var result = original.apply(this, arguments);
    if(inject_after) injection.apply(this, arguments);
    return result;
    }
}

// insert before
someFunc = injectFunc(someFunc, function(arg) {alert("Before" + arg)});

// or with string func name
someFunc = injectFunc('someFunc', function(arg) {alert("Before" + arg)});

// and after
someFunc = injectFunc(someFunc, function(arg) {alert("After" + arg)}, true);


// and with olny func name 
window['someFunc'] = injectFunc('someFunc', function(arg) {alert("After" + arg)}, true);
```

all injections are stored in function

Answer (score 0):

If you know the function and it is in global scope, you can reference it with bracket notation.

```
var orgFunction = window["functionName"];
```

so `getFunction` would look something like

```
function getFunction (name) {\
     return window[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it & replace it;

```
//original
function someId(arg) { alert(arg); }

//replace    
(function() {
    var original_function = window["someId"];
    window.someId = function(arg) { 
       alert("new");
       return original_function.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();

//call     
someId("hello");
```